# Differentiation of a function including vector

Tags: derivatives, vector-analysis

$\beta$ and $x$ are $r\times 1$ vectors. 
$\Sigma$ is a $r\times r$ symmetric matrix. 
$f(\cdot)$ is a function of $\frac{\beta^Tx}{(\beta^T\Sigma\beta)^{1/2}}$. 
How do we get the following quantity? 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial\beta\partial\beta^T}=
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\beta\partial\beta^T}f\left(\frac{\beta^Tx}{(\beta^T\Sigma\beta)^{1/2}}\right).\end{eqnarray*}
It would be appreciated if you let me know how to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Use Chain rule, call $t = \frac{\beta^T x}{(\beta^T \Sigma \beta)^{1/2}}$

The first derivative is

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f(t)}{\partial \beta}
=
\frac{\partial f(t)}{\partial t}
\frac{\partial t}{\partial \beta}
\end{equation}
The first term depends on the function as for the second term:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial t}{\partial \beta}
=
\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}
\Big(
\frac{\beta^T x}{(\beta^T \Sigma \beta)^{1/2}}
\Big)
=
\frac{(\beta^T \Sigma \beta)^{1/2}x    - \frac{\beta^Tx}{\sqrt{\beta^T\Sigma\beta}}\Sigma\beta}{(\beta^T \Sigma \beta)}
\end{equation}
which could be further simplified.
I leave the second derivative to you.

Comment: Thank you. It is very helpful!